# ideal topology and completion relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

Let $R$ be a unital ring. Declare the following sets $U$ as open.

$U$ is open if $\forall x\in U$ there is an ideal $J$ s.t. $x+J\subset U$.

I can demonstrate this being topology but I could not see its significance. It also seems that if I assume $R$ locally compact and local, then I get $R\to\hat{R}$($\hat{R}$ is completion against maximal ideal) continuous. Furthermore, it also seems that those translated $J$ in this setting become the covering of $U$ if I have $R$ locally compact and local.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Can someone elaborate a bit on importance of ideal topology and its relation to completion? This is merely mentioned in Lang's Real and Functional Analysis Book without any further discussion.

Ref. Lang, Real and Functional Analysis 3rd Ed, Chpt 2, Sec 1, pg 21, Example 6.(ideal topology)